# Magic link and "message.state is null or empty" in production

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We followed the example for magic links from here
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-with-magic-link

We can generate the magic link, are redirected to our application with an "id_token" but we get error "message.state is null or empty".

We assume that we need to follow the instructions for production use in chapter "Using this in your Production Application" on the page above, but we don't understand how we can use the "authentication library" to generate the magic link for us as described. Maybe this library would append a "state" to our magic link which is then validated by B2C.

Is there any working sample code which works in production systems for magic links?

Update:

We use already a B2C policy "B2C_1A_signup_signin" (for local and social accounts) with callback path "/signin-oidc". Therefore we added with "services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication" another callback path for the magic link "/signin-oidc-magic" with a second policy "B2C_1A_signup_signin_magic".

We generate the magic link "manually" (like in the sample project) with "/signin-oidc-magic" as return url.

B2C redirects correctly to this callback path, and the OpenIdConnectEvents for the second callback path are raised, but in event OnRemoteFailure we get the error message "message.state" is null.
Should we merge both policies? Or is something wrong in our approach?

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this myself for a while. The way I understand it now, is that in order for the magic link to redirect properly to your application after getting the token back from Ad B2C it should not be passed straight to the 'Run now' link for the custom policy but first to your application to extract the token and then passed to the OnRedirectToIdentityProviderFunc as in the documentation mentioned in the answer above. It think that does mean that you need to merge the claims extraction technical profile in to the same custom policy as the regular signin/signup flow and you can't have 2 separate custom policies but I would like to get more clarification on this myself as this use case is definitely not obvious from the samples. What good is it if they can only redirect to a jwt.ms but not an actual application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the hint parameter to your app, and have your apps authentication library pass it in an authentication request to B2C.

JS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-spa-app-options#pass-an-id-token-hint

.Net: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-application-options#pass-an-id-token-hint

Comment: Thx for your quick reponse, but seems that we are missing something. Edited the question to add more details.

Comment: It’s because your magic link should be in the format myapp.com/foo?hint=idtokenhintvalue. And your app should then make a proper auth request by parsing the query parameter and passing the hint value to the auth library like in the links I’ve shared. You can’t send the user directly to b2clogin.com with an id token hint when integrating with an app.